# Can I change or remove parentheses in a proposition consisting of conjunctions?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Can I rewrite the first line as the second?

$$(A \land \lnot B) \land (C \land \lnot D)\tag{1}$$
and $$A \land \lnot B \land C \land \lnot D\tag{2}$$

Comment: Since $\land$ is associative, if you agree that $\lnot$ is done before all else, then yes.

Comment: check the associative law for the conjunction.

Comment: This isn't technically about mathematics either, since you haven't defined what you mean when you use ^ multiple times without grouping.  If you're already assuming ^ is associative then there's not really a question here, unless you're asking about a specific programming language, in which case this isn't a math question.

Comment: @ErickWong - I think it's safe to assume that the OP is asking about the **convention of operational order** in propositional calculus, as per the tags. i.e. the `BIMDAS' for logic.

Comment: @Myridium That's definitely one possibility that hadn't occurred to me, but a lack of inner parentheses in the first line suggests that the OP is not concerned with the relative precedence of negation and conjunction.  My impression was that OP is asking whether the two expressions are equivalent according to some fixed interpreter, and it still isn't clear to me what OP intends by the unbracketed use of the conjunction operator (it is pairwise conjunction, or n-ary?)

Comment: @ErickWong - I think **it still isn't clear to me what OP intends by the unbracketed use of the conjunction operator** is exactly what the OP is asking-- what does the second expression mean? (They probably suspect the answer, or otherwise read it somewhere). Conjunction is an associative operator, so there is a natural extension to make it $n$-ary as well. This means the brackets can be safely omitted. The OP is currently grappling with this concept I think.

Answer (score 3):

Conjunction ("and", denoted "$\land$"), is indeed associative.

That means,  you can move or remove parentheses among consecutive conjunctions within a proposition without changing the truth-value of that proposition.  So yes,

$$(A \land \lnot B) \land (C \land \lnot D) \equiv A \land (\lnot B\land C) \land \lnot D \equiv A\land \lnot B \land C \land \lnot D$$

(Note that conjunction is also *commutative*, meaning $A\land B \equiv B\land A$)

In fact, see the Wikipedia entry addressing [properties of logical connectives,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_connective#Properties) for a summary.